# Using linq to select all tables in database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I want to select list of all tables (Not columns) in a database using LINQ dynamically.

I just want it Dynamically not what listed in DataContext static values.For example i alter Table2 after deploying program. in this situation how i should find it.

By the way of there are any query also please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get tables that are modeled you can use @Mygyll answer, but if you want to list all tables in database you can use `SMO`, in smo when you have a database you can get all tables via this code

`db.Tables.Cast<Table>()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the "Mapping" feature of LINQ:

```
context.Mapping.GetTables();
```